# The same dependency is included many times in my bundle

Tags: webpack

In my bundle, the same `node_modules/bn.js/lib` dependency is included *8 times* in my production bundle.

[image]

Any idea why and how to prevent it?

Comment: When using [inspectpack](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/inspectpack) I don't get any duplicate warnings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, I was able to add a [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to my config.

```js
const p = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'bn.js': p.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js'),
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Not sure if that's the right way, but it's no longer duplicated in my bundle.

Comment: Thanks Grant, this also helped me fix my issue with bn.js being included multiple times!

Comment: When I try this the build fails with `p is not defined`.  How is p declared in your config?

Comment: You'll need to require path, `const p = require('path')` at the top of the file.